# JSF application migration from JBoss AS 6 to 7 - a4j:jsFunction behaving strangely

Tags: richfaces, jboss7.x, mojarra

I'm currently in the process of migrating a JSF application (currently running with JBoss AS6 / Mojarra 2.1.6 / RichFaces 4.1.0) to JBoss 7.1.1 with the included JSF implementation (a modified Mojarra 2.1.7 afaik).

Now, at some point in my code I am using an a4j:jsFunction:

```
<a4j:jsFunction id="copyItems" name="copyItems" status="loader" render="popUpWindow" rendered="#{!cc.attrs.showForecasts}">
    <a4j:param name="selection" assignTo="#{itemListController.selectedItems}" />
</a4j:jsFunction>
```

In itemListController we have this setup:

```
public class ItemListController
{
    private String[] selectedItems;

    public void setSelectedItems(String[] selectedItems)
    {
        this.selectedItems = selectedItems;
    }

    //Getter for selectedItems and lots of other stuff follows here...
}
```

Somehwere in my code I'm having an a4j commandLink with this onclick handler:

```
onclick="copyItems(['1']);"
```

In JBoss6 this resulted in a call to setSelectedItems() with selectedItems being a String array containing the String '1'.

In JBoss7, however, I am getting an exception that essentially says "String 1 cannot be converted to a String".

Any ideas?